# Strip links from the_content

Tags: the-content

I'm trying to strip all the a href tags from `the_content();` when displayed on the front end. If I use `get_the_content();` and `preg_replace` it works fine, however, get_the_content doesn't show formatting such as `<p>` etc. When used with `the_content();`, it doesn't strip the links out.

This strips out the links, but doesn't show the formatting such as `<p>`:

```
$the_content = get_the_content();
$bad_tags = array('/<a title=\"(.*?)\" href=\"(.*?)\">/', '/<\/a>/');
$strip_tags = preg_replace($bad_tags, "", $the_content);
echo $strip_tags;
```

This DOESN'T strip out the links but does show the formatting:

```
$the_content = the_content();
$bad_tags = array('/<a title=\"(.*?)\" href=\"(.*?)\">/', '/<\/a>/');
$strip_tags = preg_replace($bad_tags, "", $the_content);
echo $strip_tags;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `get_the_content()`. You just need to use it cleverly. By default, `get_the_content()` returns the raw, non-formatted `post_content` field from the post object. In order to get formatted text, you need to run the result from `get_the_content()` though the `the_content` filters. This is exactly what `the_content()` does by default.

You can adjust your code to the following

```
$the_content = get_the_content();
$bad_tags    = ['/<a title=\"(.*?)\" href=\"(.*?)\">/', '/<\/a>/'];
$strip_tags  = preg_replace( $bad_tags, "" , $the_content );
echo apply_filters( 'the_content', $strip_tags );
```

### EDIT

From comments, you should upgrade to at least PHP 5.6. Short array syntax only works from PHP 5.4, so that all means that you have a dinosaur version of PHP. This is a huge security risk to your site as all versions below PHP 5.5 is **not** supported anymore. Take note, PHP 5.5 will reach EOL in July, all updates, accept security updates, have been stopped already

### PRE PHP 5.4 version

```
$the_content = get_the_content();
$bad_tags    = array( '/<a title=\"(.*?)\" href=\"(.*?)\">/', '/<\/a>/' );
$strip_tags  = preg_replace( $bad_tags, "" , $the_content );
echo apply_filters( 'the_content', $strip_tags );
```

Comment: Thanks Pieter, that worked, although `['/<a title=\"(.*?)\" href=\"(.*?)\">/', '/<\/a>/'] `was giving me an error so I changed it back to `array('/<a title=\"(.*?)\" href=\"(.*?)\">/', '/<\/a>/')` and it works lovely!

Comment: My pleasure. Upgrade to PHP 5.6. Short array only works from PHP 5.4, so you have a really old PHP version which you should not use due to security issues

Comment: I'm running version 5.5 at the moment. Always dubious about updating php versions with wordpress as it often breaks stuff!

Comment: Actually, I just checked. It was my code editing software that was showing the syntax error. Your original answer works fine with php 5.5 so I have marked it as answered. Thanks.

Comment: Most probably dreamweaver I suspect. The old version throws errors everywhere if you use PHP 5.4+  syntax ;-)